# Track down what's causing slow rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rspec

The specs for my rails project have been really slow lately. I did a git bisect to see if I could determine what has been slowing it and I found that certain commits that were previously running just fine are now just as slow as the current HEAD.

This leads me to believe that my problem is being caused by a gem updating or something else that's not under my source control. The problem still occurs on other dev machines so I don't think it's my personal environment either.

What's the best way to track down my slowest tests and then figure out what's slowing them down so much?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This flag will tell you which tests are the bottlenecks:

```
$ rspec --profile
```

Comment: and the bottlenecks in those tests?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the test prof gem:

https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/?id=recipes

https://github.com/palkan/test-prof